# split string at every character

Tags: r, perl

I want to split every character in a string and output it as comma or tab separated characters:
I need to use `file_in` and `file_out` since I have very many lines.

input

```
TTTGGC
TTTG
TGCAATGG
....
....
```

output

```
T,T,T,G,G,C
T,T,T,G
T,G,C,A,A,T,G,G
```

I have used this, but it prints every character vertically:

```
  /usr/bin/perl
   use strict;
   use warnings;

    my $data = 'Becky Alcorn';

   my @values = split(undef,$data);

  foreach my $val (@values) {
   print "$val\n";
  }

  exit 0;
```

Comment: I don't know Perl, but I guess that if you replace `"$val\n"` with `"$val,"` it should work, or be more close to what you want to achieve.

Comment: @RitchMelton, stop deleting the tags if the OP is interested in a solution using any of these tools. That's not really your decision to make.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto - Where did he say he was interested in that?

Comment: @AnandaMahto the tags are inappropriate. There's no content in the question about any of those languages.

Comment: @RitchMelton, he tagged it with those tools and you keep removing the tags.

Comment: @hobbs, then perhaps the question needs editing, not the tags.

Comment: I removed the tags because people routinely over tag. Its a benign thing. I thought somebody stomped on my edit, so I re-did it. You are assuming maliciousness where none exists.

Comment: @AnandaMahto but then again probably not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In R, you can use `strsplit` and `paste`:

```
Strings <- c("TTTGGC","TTTG","TGCAATGG")
vapply(strsplit(Strings, ""), function(x) paste(x, collapse=","), character(1L))
# [1] "T,T,T,G,G,C"     "T,T,T,G"         "T,G,C,A,A,T,G,G"
```

You can write the output using `writeLines`, specifying `sep = "\n"` if required.

Comment: +1 Just another idea: `gsub("(?!^|$)", ",", Strings, perl = T)`

Answer (score 3):

Your code uses a loop to print the values of `@values` one per line, so the computer does what you told it to. Try:

```
print join ",", @values;
```

or even condense your code all the way down to:

```
print join ",", split //, $data;
```

Answer (score 3):

Using perl one-liner,

```
perl -F -lane 'print join ",", @F' file
```

output

```
T,T,T,G,G,C
T,T,T,G
T,G,C,A,A,T,G,G
```

Comment: +1 TIMTOWTDI : `perl -F -lane '$,=",";print @F' file` though I am not sure if setting `$,` for each line can become a big overhead. Probably throw it in the `BEGIN` block.

Answer (score 1):

awk one-liner:

```
awk -v FS='' -v OFS="," '$1=$1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
open my $in, '<','in.txt';
open my $out, '>', 'out.txt';

while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    my @split = split(//);
    print $out join ",", @split;
    print $out "\n";
}
```

Comment: I assume down vote was due extra comma at the end of the line.

Comment: @mpapec That's what I thought. I have corrected to address this

Answer (score 1):

Or with the `stringr` package:

```
txt <- c("TTTGGC", "TTTG", "TGCAATGG") 
unlist(str_split(string=txt, pattern= ""))
 [1] ""  "T" "T" "T" "G" "G" "C" ""  "T" "T" "T" "G" ""  "T" "G" "C" "A" "A" "T" "G" "G"
```

Comment: Uhh, what?  I don't think that's the result OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and easy method that uses base R functions. The documentation for `paste` actually notes  that `paste` can be used as the "the opposite" of `strsplit`

`paste0` with `collapse = ","` is nice here

```
> txt <- c("TTTGGC", "TTTG", "TGCAATGG")  ## your data
> sapply(strsplit(txt, ""), paste0, collapse = ",")
# [1] "T,T,T,G,G,C"     "T,T,T,G"         "T,G,C,A,A,T,G,G"
```